# Java Selenium / HtmlunitDriver opens wrong website

Tags: java, selenium, unicode, utf-8, htmlunit

I try to open a website by using `driver.get(url):

```
    driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    driver.setAcceptSslCertificates(true);
    driver.setDownloadImages(true);

    driver.get(<private url>);
```

However, the URL contains an 'Ö', a german Umlaut.
So the driver replaces 'ö' with '%D6'

So it opens a wrong site.

I tried changing to `UTF-8` in Eclipse; didn't work.

Also using unicode didn't work.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Can you give a sample URL? Which part of the URL contains the Umlaut? Hostname, query, or parameters?

Comment: Example: https//example.anotherexample.net/aWordwithÖ.php

Comment: @KevinMeyer `https//example.anotherexample.net/aWordwithÖ.php` is not a valid url. Can you get me a realtime example of an URL which contains an 'Ö', a german Umlaut? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case works with `2.27-SNAPSHOT`.

indexÖ.html:

```html
<body>Ö</body>
```

Java code:

```java
    WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    driver.get("http://localhost:8080/indexÖ.html");
    System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<html>
  <head/>
  <body>
    Ã
  </body>
</html>
```

which is what real Chrome also shows.

As you said, ensure your all workspace is in UTF-8:
[image]

And if you are using maven:

```xml
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Comment: 2.27 Snapshot of Selenium?

Comment: 2.27-snapshot `htmlunit-driver` and `htmlunit`, check [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver), may be you are using the old `artifactId`

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't find a .jar libary for 2.27 :C

Comment: Snapshot is in maven, you can use 2.26 for now

Comment: And how do I add 2.27?

Comment: [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver/releases/tag/untagged-64d3ac43a7ef7a07f357)